# Value in array CodeIgniter validation rule

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, validationrules

CodeIgniter has many validation rules but is there any rule for checking if the value from a certain field is present in an array(given as parameter to the validation rule)?

For example:

```
$possible_values = array('beer', 'soda', 'wine', 'water');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('drink', 'Drink', 'required|trim|found_in_array[possible_values]');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `callback_function_name` like so,

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('drink', 'Drink',  'callback_customInArray');


public function customInArray($str)
    {
        $possible_values = array('beer', 'soda', 'wine', 'water');
        if(in_array($str, $possible_values){return true;}
        return false;
    }
```

read more about that in [CI Form Validation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't a validation rule for that specific case.

But you can create your own validation rules: Look [here (Codeingiter UserGuide)](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks)

I.E.:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_is_inArray[someValues]');

public function is_inArray($str, $values) {
   return in_array($str, $values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in_list` codeigniter form validation rule.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('drink', 'Drink', 'in_list[beer,soda,wine,water]');
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.